# Rails - Where should controller helpers go?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Following is my use case -

I have a controller method(action) that makes an API call to Google. I have created a class `Google` which I have put in `lib` folder. Class `Google` provides the api call method.

```
def self.list_items(folder_id, access_token)
    result = RestClient.get "#{API_URL}/drive/v2/files",
                            {
                                :Authorization => "Bearer #{access_token}",
                                :params => {:q => "'#{folder_id}' in parents and trashed=false"}
                            }
    return JSON.parse(result)['items']
  end
```

However, I need to write a method that calls `list_items` from `Google`, catches exception in case access_token expires, refreshes access_token, saves the new access_token in database and makes the `list_items` call again.

Since this method needs to interact with database, I don't want to put it in a class in `lib`. I am new to rails, and I have understood that `lib` folder should have third party code. Class `Google` here can be considered a third party class as its a PORO without anything to do with rails project or my business logic. Please correct me if this understanding is wrong.

I can keep this method as a private method in controller, but assume there are multiple such methods. Won't that make the controller fat?

Also, the controller is `FileApiController`, while all these methods are google specific. I also have methods specific to box and dropbox. I would ideally like to create `GoogleHelper`, `DropboxHelper` etc. classes, which interact with db as well. Where to keep this classes?

I come from Grails background, and `GoogleHelper` would typically be made as a service in Grails like googleService. What is the rails way of doing it. Specifically, if I make a `GoogleHelper` class, where to keep it? I guess, helper folder is only to keep view helpers.

Answer (score 2):

Create file in `app/helpers/google_helper.rb`

```
module GoogleHelper

 class << self

  def print_hello
     puts 'HELLO WORLD'
  end      


  def list_items(folder_id, access_token)
    result = RestClient.get "#{API_URL}/drive/v2/files",
                            {
                                :Authorization => "Bearer #{access_token}",
                                :params => {:q => "'#{folder_id}' in parents and trashed=false"}
                            }
    return JSON.parse(result)['items']
  end
 end
end
```

If you want to call `GoogleHelper` in controllers then add it in `application_controller.rb` this `include GoogleHelper`

Now you can call your helper: `GoogleHelper.print_hello` in a controller.

Comment: You can remove the code inside list_items as I will instead call `Google.list_items` here. Your solution seems good, but I thought the classes under helpers folder are mostly for view helper. is it a common practice to keep controller helpers under helpers folder?

Comment: Yes, its good practice, to use helpers for controllers and view.

Comment: Also, you can call Helpers `GoogleHelper.print_hello` in the MODEL files too.